# Why won't this VBA If True Then statement compile?

Tags: vba

Here's the code snippet

```
Dim POSelectedNum As CimObjectVariable
Set POSelectedNum = CimGetScriptOwner().GetVariable("POSelectedNum")

If (StrComp("POSelectedNum" = "POSelectedNum", vbTextCompare) = 0) = True
Then POSelectedNum = ""
End IF
```

I keep getting this error:

> Error 168 in line 44: Encountered: end of line
>
> Expecting: , Then

And there's a red bar at the end of True.  I searched for Error 168 on VBA but came up dry.  Any help?

Comment: If your question has been answered, please mark an answer as "accepted" by clicking the hollow checkmark next to it. That will remove your question from the pool of unanswered questions. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

I imagine that you mean this:

```
Dim POSelectedNum As CimObjectVariable
Set POSelectedNum = CimGetScriptOwner().GetVariable("POSelectedNum")

If StrComp(POSelectedNum, "POSelectedNum", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
    POSelectedNum = ""
End IF
```

Comment: I would remove the parenthesis `CimGetScriptOwner.GetVariable("POSelectedNum")`

Answer (score 2):

It won't compile because the statement is grammatically incorrect.

There are two valid syntaxes for an `If` statement.

Inline:

```
If {bool-expression} Then {statement}
```

Block:

```
If {bool-expression} Then
    {statements}
End If
```

Anything else is a compile error.

---

If you *really* want the `Then` part on another line together with the statement that follows, you could use the *inline* syntax with *line continuations* (underscores):

```
If {bool-expression} _
Then {statement}
```

Note the absence of an `End If` token: while there are 2 "physical" lines of code, as far as VBA is concerned this is one single "logical" line of code, and parses as a correct inline syntax.